# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of: Inside Ionic project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic + Angular project and I get the error mentioned in the question title since I have used the **ngIf** directive in the template. I have already imported CommonModule too. Could you please help me find a solution.

**My AppModule file**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy},
        HttpClientModule,
        AuthGuard,
        AuthService,
        DataService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**App routing config**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthGuard} from './auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
    },
    // .... other routes
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

The template in question is inside the **RegisterPage** in **HomeModule**.

**HomeModule**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HomeRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomeModule {
}
```

Following is the template part that causes the error.

```
<ion-spinner *ngIf="loading"></ion-spinner>
```

The **loading** variable has been declared in the Typescript file.

The **angular** version is 9.1.6 and the **Ionic** version is 5.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

I dont see the `RegisterPage` declared in your `HomeModule`.
Either add `RegisterPage` to the declarations, or if it is declared in another module, make sure that `CommonModule` is imported in that module as well.

Comment: I have already fixed the problem. And you are correct, I have forgotten to declare the RegisterPage in HomeModule.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the directive for *ngIf is not known to the ionic components.

Please replace your html code with:

```
<div *ngIf="loading">
<ion-spinner ></ion-spinner>
</div>
```

Comment: that is not true. and if it was, it would be more appropiate to use ```<ng-container *ngIf="something"></ng-container>``` instead of a div